# Excluding bad data from a numeric array

Tags: python

Im trying to scatter some data for a project in Python, but I have some bad values that I'm trying to exclude. All my data are arrays containing numbers, they are: `P0_d, P0_m, P0_b ; al_d, al_m, al_b`

The code is:

```
ii = (al_m>-400) & (al_b>-400)

scat1 = scatter(P0_d, al_d, color ='blue', s=200)
scat2 = scatter(P0_m[ii], al_m[ii], color='green', marker='^', s=200, alpha=0.8)
scat3 = scatter(P0_b[ii], al_b[ii], color='red', marker='s', s=200, alpha=0.6)
```

The error that is shown is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-467-2d64e43bad52> in <module>()
      5 scat1 = scatter(P0_d, al_d, color ='blue', s=200)
      6 scat2 = scatter(P0_m[ii], al_m[ii], color='green', marker='^', s=200, alpha=0.8)
----> 7 scat3 = scatter(P0_b[ii], al_b[ii], color='red', marker='s', s=200, alpha=0.6)


TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I looked at several answers but didn't find anything that worked here. I'm not very tech-savvy, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This seems incomplete.  For instance, what is P0_b?

Comment: Oh sorry, my data are P0_d, P0_m, P_b  and  al_d, al_m, al_b. I'll edit for clarity

Comment: Submit your full code.  What values are you assigning to those arrays?  It seems like There is an assignment for either P0_b or al_b that isn't sitting right.  With more info I could give it my two cents.